# Validating a downloading file

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I have some files in server that users can download it but user must be logged in to download those files so files are in format of rar or zip. is there any way to validate that use is already logged before downloading files in php  ?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) AND isset($_COOKIE['hash']) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['url']) {
        Header("Location:".$_SESSION['url']);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The same way that you validate the user is already logged in before giving them any other content that requires a login.

Comment: i can validate through a php file but how to validate a rar file ?

Comment: @Shn Hint: A php file does not have to return a html document.

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad. Please give more details on how you are currently checking that the user is logged in to serve other content, and where the file is stored that you want to serve. Edit this information into your question.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i have updated the question with code that i used i validate user with cookies

Comment: @Shn — The same way. User requests a URL. URL is handled by PHP. PHP returns the data (the rar) the user is asking for (with a suitable content-type header).

Comment: @Quentin after i return the header to the file the file url will be visible to the downloaded user who was logged in so he can download it next time with the rar file url without logging in i need a solution for this i already managed others

Comment: @Shn — Don't give the *file* a URL. The PHP should return the file.

Comment: @Quentin i tried it in this way but if a user using any download manager php file execute 2 or more time i record each download so it create many duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah below is approach to use
step1:prevent zip file direct access

order allow,deny
  deny from all

step2:

```
<?php
function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');
 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "jpg" => "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html"=> "text/html",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
 @ob_end_clean(); 

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
 ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* Will output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        echo($buffer); 
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else
 //If no permissiion
 die('Error - can not open file.');
 //die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);

//path to the file
$file_path='files/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];


//Call the download function with file path,file name and file type

if($_SESSION['userloggedin']){
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
}else{
    echo "login";
}
?>
```

Comment: U just can use `readile()` to offer the zip as download. Then u don't need that byte read construction

Comment: yeah but u can use above code to download all type of files like zip or something else

Comment: Is this code safe? `fseek(..)` does not prevent you from setting the pointer **after** where the file ends and the docs for `feof(...)` say it only returns true *at* EOF, not necessarily after EOF.

Comment: @gaurav Well, not really. It does no check what filename you request, so you can dump the contents of this file, or any other file in this directory, and any other file in parent directories without a problem. After some testing, `fseek()` and `feof()` work as I expect them to. `fread(..)` does correct this silently though, and the script seems to check the `filesize(..)` to ensure it doesn't try to read outside the file.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yeah sure if any modification needed pls do it you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like any other content you are serving. A php file does not have to return a `text/html` document. It can serve any data, including images, pdf's or executables. You just have to serve it with the right headers.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['hash'])
{
  //The user is logged in... we have no clue if the user is allowed to download the file
  header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
  header( "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache" );

  file_get_contents( "images/image.jpg" );
  exit();
} else {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit();
}
```

The cache-control header is here to prevent servers between the client and your server from caching this request. ISP's sometimes do this to serve common files faster. The content-type header should be set to the correct mime-type based on what file you are serving. You can find a list of common mime types on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#List_of_common_media_types).

**IMPORTANT**

This answer uses 'file_get_contents(...)'. You should always make sure that the url that is passed to this function is sane. This means: It should point to an existing file, and it should only point to a file you actually want to serve. If someone passes '../../../.htaccess' you don't want to accidentally spill the contents of that file to the user!